# Validating user email authentication

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am prompting my app users for email credentials.

After the user insert email and pass I want to validate the account.

I am using **javax.mail**. Is there any way to validate the account? only make sure that the credentials are indeed valid - else I want to show an invalid user and pass message.

Maybe some way to perform:

```
Transport.send(message);
```

And check for authentication exceptions while not sending anything.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do something like this

```
public final static boolean validateEmail(CharSequence givenSeq) {
    if (givenSeq!= null) {
         return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(givenSeq).matches();
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create plausibility checks like (just examples, far away from complete):

```
String email = "anonym.user@mail.com";

if (!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".") || !(email.lastIndexOf(".") > email.indexOf("@")))
    showError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * validate your email address format. Ex-xyz@abc.com
 */
public boolean emailValidator(String email) 
{
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Transport object and manage the connection to verify that the username/pass works.

```
Address[] to = InternetAddress.parse("me@localhost");
Transport t = session.getTransport(to[0]);
t.connect();
t.close();
```

If you want to verify the username/pass and the envelope simply create a message that has all of the envelope information set but has no content.  Or create a subclass of MimeMessage that has hostile writeTo(OutputStream) methods.

```
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    Address[] from = InternetAddress.parse("me@localhost");
    Address[] to = InternetAddress.parse("me@localhost");
    msg.addFrom(from);
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(384);
    msg.saveChanges();
    try {
        msg.writeTo(out);
        throw new AssertionError();
    } catch (MessagingException | IOException test) {
        try {
            Transport.send(msg);
            throw new AssertionError();
        } catch (MessagingException | IOException expect) {
            if (!exceptionEqual(test, expect)) {
                //Notify the user....
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason this works is that the content is written last so if Transport.send makes it to Message.writeTo then you know without a doubt that you can login to the mail server. Additionally, the server will let you know if it accepted the envelope information.  However, just because it accepted the envelope doesn't mean the delivery will succeed.  Because Message.writeTo throws an exception, no actual email message will be sent.